# MySQL join query with IF CONDITION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables Customer & Company

**COMPANY**

```
COMP_ID | COMP_NAME  
1       | Google      
2       | Facebook
```

**CUSTOMER**

```
CUST_ID | COMP_ID | CUST_NAME    
1       | 1       | John         
2       | 2       | NULL          
3       | 2       | Rob
```

I want to write a query to display `CUST_NAME` as `CONTACT` but if `CUST_NAME` is `NULL`, then display `COMP_NAME` as `CONTACT`

Comment: @ChipDean I wrote separate query and doing if else in PHP but now want to do that in one query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
select cs.cust_id, coalesce(cs.cust_name, co.comp_name) contact
from customer cs
inner join company co
on cs.comp_id = co.comp_id;
```

If you have got empty string in cust_name do this:

```
select cs.cust_id, coalesce(nullif(cs.cust_name,''), co.comp_name) contact
from t_customer cs
inner join t_company co
on cs.comp_id = co.comp_id;
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rextester.com/ATWU62438)

Comment: @Arif added a demo for you

Comment: ok I just noticed, its working for NULL but if the field is empty I mean if the NULL is not checked then its not working. I try `IF(cs.cust_name='', co.comp_name, cs.cust_name)` which is doing the opposite to NULL and empty

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve same by if or case

```
 select IF(cs.CUST_NAME IS NULL or cs.CUST_NAME = '', co.comp_name,cs.cust_name) as contact,
case when cs.CUST_NAME IS NULL or cs.CUST_NAME = '' then co.comp_name else cs.cust_name end as usingcasecontact
from customer cs
inner join  company co
on cs.comp_id = co.comp_id;
```

check its [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a37fe/9)